# Format a number to always have a sign and decimal separator

Tags: c#, .net, format, string-formatting

I want to format any number (integer or real) to a string representation which **always** has **a sign** (positive or negative) and a **decimal separator**, but no trailing zeroes.

Some samples:

```
3.14 => +3.14
12.00 => +12.
-78.4 => -78.4
-3.00 => -3.
```

Is it possible with one of the default `ToString()` implementations, or do I need write this myself?

Comment: There exists no already implemented way to display a decimal separator  followed by nothing (AFAIK). So you have to implement this on yourself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
double x = -12.43;
string xStr = x.ToString("+0.#####;-0.#####");
```

But this wouldn't help to display trailing decimal point. You can handle such situations using this method:

```
public static string MyToString(double x)
{
    return x == Math.Floor(x)
        ? x.ToString("+0;-0;0") + CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator
        : x.ToString("+0.####;-0.####");
}
```

Comment: Probably the best answer yet. But, I feel that we cannot force the decimal point if they are no trailing zeroes.

Comment: Ok, now it works exactly like I want! Thanks!

Comment: Assuming this is supposed to be an extension method, the `this` keyword is missing. i.e. `public static string MyToString(this double x)`

Comment: @WyattEarp I agree, it makes sense, thank you. And I have to add to your comment that in this case the method should be placed in a `static` class.

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this:

```
string myFormatedString = number.ToString("+#;-#");
```

Comment: This doesn't display digits after the decimal separator.

Answer (score 0):

The format string you want to use is

```
ToString("N", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) // Displays -12,445.68
```

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k(v=vs.110).aspx) for additional options for format strings

Comment: This does not display the ending decimal point if there are no trailing zeroes.