# TextBlock string format with dot WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, string-formatting

How to get `3.`, without the trailing zero, but with the decimal separator. For example, value `3.0` must be `3.` and the value `3.1` must be `3.1`.

I tried to use:

```
<TextBlock Binding="{Binding Y, StringFormat='0.'} />
```

But, it doesn't work, for a value `3.0` result is `3`.

If it only code behind issue, how can I resolve it?

I'm sorry about my bad English:(

Comment: `3.1` should stay as `3.1`

Comment: You might need to do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25725439/1136211) in a [binding converter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.converter.aspx).